# How to find out if user is logged in having httpOnly JWT token cookie?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, jwt

I am writing React app and I have server that returns JWT token in httpOnly secure cookie. I am aware that JS can't read httpOnly cookies but I need to find out if user is authenticated or not. I discarded localStorage approach because its not very secure and I want to know a nice way ('best practice' if I can say so) to store JWT token and have a way to find out if user is authenticated.

Comment: 1) PIN Number ATM Machine JWT Token.  2) How is React going to get a token that it can't read?  3) If you want to keep an active user logged in many authentication systems have a refresh() api you can call periodically to extend the token.  As written your question is unclear.